# Content Page does not have content of Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Master Page Content :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
    <center>
   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-top-width:0" bordercolor="red" width="970" bgcolor="#DDE1EE" cellpadding="0">
//all contents

</table>   
    </center>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

COntent Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CambridgeMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</asp:Content>
```

In my content page, I am unable to find any Master Page content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works a bit differently.

It injects the content of your Content page into the ContentPlaceholders (effectively replacing anything there).

You can put your ContentPlaceholder where you want the content page html to appear.

```
    <center>
   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-top-width:0" bordercolor="red" width="970" bgcolor="#DDE1EE" cellpadding="0">
//all contents
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"> 
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</table>   
    </center>
```

Note that i've placed it inside the table and left it empty.

Comment: But, Now, my things from content pages are intersecting with page content